# differentiation a integral

Tags: calculus, integration

here is the problem

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} (t+\tau)^2 d\tau = ?$

this is my calculation

first,let

$ f(\tau)=(t+\tau)^2 $
$ F(\tau)=\int f(\tau)d\tau $

$ F'(\tau)= f(\tau) $

so,
$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} (t+\tau)^2 d\tau  $

$=\frac{d}{dt}(F(t)-F(0)) $

$=F'(t)-F'(0) $

$=f(t)-f(0) $

$=(t+t)^2-(t+0)^2 $

$=2t^2-t^2=t^2$

However,the solution is

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} (t+\tau)^2 d\tau $             .......................................(1)

$=(t+t)^2+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{d}{\partial t}  (t+\tau)^2 d\tau $.................(2)

$=(t+t)^2+\int_{0}^{t} 2 (t+\tau) d\tau $

$=(t+t)^2+ (2t\tau+\tau^2)|_0^t $

$=4t^2+ (2t^2+t^2) $

$=7t^2$

**I have two question,**

1.What am I doing wrong with my calculation

2.how to derive equation(2) from equation(1)

Thanks!

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Note that while you should take this opportunity to learn and understand the Leibniz rule, it is by no means necessary here. The integral can be done by the usual rules to give $\frac{1}{3}((2t)^3-t^3))$ which can then be differentiated to give $7t^2.$ The Leibniz rule is useful, however, when the integral can’t be so easily done. (And of course you need to know it so you don’t apply a FTC-like thing incorrectly, as you did here.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple application of Lebinitz rule and product rule

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} (t+\tau)^{2}d\tau \\ = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t}(t^2 + \tau^2 + 2 t \tau)d\tau \\ = \frac{d}{dt}t^2 \int_{0}^{t} d\tau + \frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} \tau^2 d\tau + 2\frac{d}{dt} t\int_{0}^{t} \tau  d\tau \\ $$ 
Now apply product rule and Lebinitz rule:

 1st integral:
$$2t\int_{0}^{t} 1. d\tau + t^2 \\ =3t^2$$


 2nd integral:
$$t^2 $$

3rd integral
$$2\int_{0}^{t}\tau d\tau + 2t^2 \\ = 2t^2+t^2 \\ = 3t^2$$

Finally we have $3t^2 + t^2 + 3t^2 = 7t^2$

To apply Lebinitz rule, the integrand must only contain variable $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

It can be calculated *without* applying the *Leibniz Rule*. First we write for every summand an integral.

$$\int_0^t t^2 \, d\tau+ \int_0^t 2t\tau d\tau + \int_0^t \tau ^2d\tau$$

Writing the constant factors in front of the integration sign.

$$t^2 \int_0^t \, d\tau+ 2t\int_0^t \tau d\tau + \int_0^t \tau ^2d\tau$$

$=t^2\left[ \tau \right]_0^t+2t\left[ \frac12\tau^2 \right]_0^t+\left[ \frac13\tau^3 \right]_0^t$

$=t^3+t^3+\frac13\cdot t^3=\frac{7}3 t^3$

Now we can differentiate $f(t)$ w.r.t $t$

$$f'(t)=3\cdot \frac{7}3 t^{3-1}=7t^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to your first question:

> first,let
>
> $ f(\tau)=(t+\tau)^2 $
>   $ F(\tau)=\int f(\tau)d\tau $
>
> $ F'(\tau)= f(\tau) $

We also have a dependency of $F$ on $t$ here. We should rather take
$$f_t(\tau) = (t+\tau)^2$$
$$F_t(\tau) = \int f_t(\tau) \, d\tau$$
$$F_t'(\tau) = f_t(\tau)$$

> so, $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} (t+\tau)^2 d\tau  $
>
> $=\frac{d}{dt}(F(t)-F(0)) $
>   $=F'(t)-F'(0) $

Don't you think that $F(0)$ looks like a constant? What is the derivative of a constant? It's zero!

But, as I said earlier, $F$ should be replaced with $F_t$, so the derivative is
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( F_t(t) - F_t(0) \right)
$$
Now, here's a problem: we need to take the derivative with respect to the index $t$ but how do we do that? Nothing says that we can just use $F_t'.$

> $=f(t)-f(0) $
>
> $=(t+t)^2-(t+0)^2 $
>
> $=2t^2-t^2=t^2$

Finally, $(t+t)^2 = (2t)^2 = 4t^2,$ *not* $= 2t^2.$

Comment: thanks for pointing out the problem ( (t+t)^2=4t^2  ) .and Could you please show how to get 7t^2 in the end

Comment: I didn't point out "the problem". There were several problems in your attempt. It's not enough to fix just one of them. For a complete solution I suggest the one written by **callculus**.